# Search object in nested object if certain condtion match

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object like below

```
temp = [
  {category: 'category1', branch: [{key: 'key A1', value: 'value A1'}, {key: 'key B1', value: 'value B1'}] },
  {category: 'category2', branch: [{key: 'key A2', value: 'value A2'}, {key: 'key B2', value: 'value B2'}] },
  {category: 'category3', branch: [{key: 'key A3', value: 'value A3'}, {key: 'key B3', value: 'value B3'}] },
  {category: 'category4', branch: [{key: 'key A4', value: 'value A4'}, {key: 'key B', value: 'value B4'}] }
]
```

I wanna find a object like `{key: 'key A3', value: 'value A3'}` if `certainValue  = 'value A3'` matched in a given object

I had written code like this

```
result = temp.map(te => te.branch.find(t => t.value === certainValue))
```

but getting undefined in result i.e. `[undefined, undefined, {key: 'key A3', value: 'value A3'}, undefined]`

So is there anyway getting exact result i.e `{key: 'key A3', value: 'value A3'}` ??

I don't wanna again iterate result for removing `undefined`.

Comment: do you have only one result to find?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for geting a flat array and then find the wanted object.

```js
var temp = [{ category: 'category1', branch: [{ key: 'key A1', value: 'value A1' }, { key: 'key B1', value: 'value B1' }] }, { category: 'category2', branch: [{ key: 'key A2', value: 'value A2' }, { key: 'key B2', value: 'value B2' }] }, { category: 'category3', branch: [{ key: 'key A3', value: 'value A3' }, { key: 'key B3', value: 'value B3' }] }, { category: 'category4', branch: [{ key: 'key A4', value: 'value A4' }, { key: 'key B', value: 'value B4' }] }],
    certainValue = 'value A3',
    result = temp
        .flatMap(({ branch }) => branch)
        .find(t => t.value === certainValue);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: just follow the link and have a look to all methods of `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

const result = temp.map(te => te.branch.find(t => t.value === certainValue)).find(item => !!item);